# How to change Tag to another name in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to change the Tag text to another name in wordpress.

What i want exactly.
For now if i am click on any tag the url will be:-
http://demo.com/tags/tagname

i want to change the tag to vehicle so that when click on it will show as:-
http://demo.com/vehicle/vehiclename

Simply i want to replace the Tag with Vehicle in wordpress.

Thanks.

Comment: If you only have tags for vehicles you can change the setting in the permalinks. If you need more the cleanest way would be to create your own Taxonomy: http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and then to Permalinks.
There you can set your tagbase to vehicles in the optional settings.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

[image: Permalink Settings]

You may enter custom bases for your category and tag URLs here. For example, using /vehicle/ as your tagbase would make your taglinks like http://example.org/vehicle/tagname/. If you leave these blank the defaults will be used. Again, see the Using Permalinks article for further discussion of Permalink Structure Tags.
Tag base - Enter a custom prefix for your tag URLs here.